# Calculating utilization based on datadifference in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table in Power Query where my projects are stored. The columns contain information on when to start the project and when to end the project and I also have the calculated hours for this project. A small samplle is given below:

| Projectnumber | Proddate | Deliverydate | Hours prod | Nettoworkdays | Time per day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 | 25/01/2023 | 25 | 18 | 1,388888889 |
| 2 | 26/03/2023 | 29/04/2023 | 50 | 25 | 2 |

But I want to built a date table where my time per project per day is indicated based on the difference between the Proddate and Deliverydate. In my example, the dates in between 01/01/2023 should have a value of 1.39 for all the days in between for project 1.

How can I do this in Power Query?

Thanks

I've tried merging the columns, calculate it in DAX, but nothing seems to give the right answers as of now.

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, add column, custom column with formula

```
=List.Transform({Number.From([Proddate])..Number.From([Deliverydate])}, each Date.From(_))
```

expand to new rows using the arrow atop the new column

Sample code

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Proddate", type datetime}, {"Deliverydate", type datetime}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Transform({Number.From([Proddate])..Number.From([Deliverydate])}, each Date.From(_))),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom")
in  #"Expanded Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: I’ll go ahead and remove my answer - this is infinitely better anyway

Comment: Your m code looked about identical   I just didn't see your answer before posting.  I would leave your answer for those who want DAX

Comment: The DAX did not cover the row expansion part :)